# Can I compute the name of a variable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to know if it is possible to compute the name of a variable in VB.net.  I need to open a bunch of text files at runtime.  The exact number will be variable.  I wanted to do something along the lines of:

```
For j = 1 to Filecount
    Dim Filename As String = "File"&j
    Dim File & j As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
Next
```

When I tried this, VB.net said it didn't like it.  Is this possible?

Comment: not really...  you'd might want to use an array, or a dictionary keyed off (File & J) to keep track of a string  to object relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off using a dictionary, which would allow you to get back to the appropriate stream writer using the filename later:

```
Dim fileDictoinary As New Dictionary(Of String, System.IO.StreamWriter)

For j = 1 To Filecount
    Dim Filename As String = "File" & j
    fileDictoinary.Add(Filename, New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename))
Next
```

Then at a later time you can access the streamwriter using the filename in the dictionary:

```
Dim file4StreamWriter = fileDictoinary("File4")
file4StreamWriter.Write(True)
```